# RDLC group by multiple column in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I am using rdlc report and using table in it.I want to make following desingn in rdlc but when i drag database column in row group table properties it shows columns on left side.I want Eng Crs Name and Arabic Crs are parent group and Eng Gender and Arb Gender are child group.Where Eng is english and Arb is Arabic.Both are same columns but different language.How can i achieve this following design.

```
  Eng CrsName        EngGender    Students      ArabicGender     ArbCrs


    engname1           EngM          2            ArabicM        arbn1
                       EngF          3            ArabicF     

   engname2           EngM           4             ArabicM       arbn2
                      EngF           5             ArabicF
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to have parent and children columns is by using the `Matrix` component. I suggest you give it try on your own first, it should be self explanatory.

If the Matrix does not meet your desires, there is another easy way to group data in an RDLC Report by using the `List` component.

You can add a table with just the table headers at the top, so it won't be repeated. And then drag the parent (column on which you wish to group) to a TextBox inside the `Rectangle` of the List. Make sure you group the List on that column.
Next you can add a Table with the children data into the rectangle. If there are multiple children, this table will generate multiple rows inside the rectangle. This rectangle will then repeat for every parent item, grouping everything nicely. You can also add lines to represent columns as you see fit.

I hope this helps you a little, if not you should describe your datasource in a bit more detail and I might be able to give a more accurate solution.

Here is a more visual representation of what i tried to explain with words:
[image]

Comment: Please give more accurate solution with image or blog

Comment: To get you started, you should take a look at [this detailed tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/767067/RDLC-Report-Grouping-with-Page-Break-Table-Header).

It's hard to do this for your situation without knowing where you get your data from. Do you get your data from a single table or multiple and what are the original columns?

Comment: i am creating  datable first and then filling this dataTable through ado.net code. u can make this through single table. I need just concept

Comment: An easy demonstration of the List grouping can be found [here](http://gotreportviewer.com/masterdetail/index.html). it's mainly Option 2 that I was describing in my answer.

Comment: Brother my problem not solved.Can you explain it in blog

Comment: These all are table column

Comment: I've added an image to help with my explanation. You should be able to replicate this on your own now if you read the documentation that I linked.